# Angular 2/8 + Mafterial Добавить иконку в Slide toggle

Tags: css, angular, material-design, angular-material

Всем привет.

Необходимо внутрь включенного Slide toggle добавить иконку, что бы выглядело вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В идеале, что бы картинку можно было брать из assets. Стандартное API не дает такой возможности. Нашел [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51512015/angular-material-mat-slide-toggle-change-toggle-icon), где кастомизировали внешний вид переключателя через CSS, но увы - ничего не вышло. Моя попытка выглядела вот так:

```
.mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked:not(.mat-disabled) .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
     background-image: url('http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_201862.png') !important;
   }
```

так же пробовал помещать картинку в content: url(...)

P/s: на цвета или привязку к функционалу не обращайте внимания. Суть вопроса именно в размещении картинки внутри переключателя потому как у меня в приниципе не выходит это сделать...
Однажды я видел подобную реализацию, но вот когда нужно - найти не получается :(

Ссылка на официальную документацию: https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/api Вдруг поможет...

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: имхо будет легче написать свой компонент, скопировав стили материала, под свои нужды, или вот смотри что нашел просто загуглив - https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-icon-toggle

Comment: @overthesanity спасибо большое!!! Я все пытался влезть в этот компонент, а погуглить аналоги даже не подумал! На первый взгляд - именно то, что я искал!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как мне подсказал [**overthesanity**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/303477/overthesanity) - я по началу взялся за пакет [simple-icon-toggle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-icon-toggle), но как оказалось - пакет работает не корректно (я создал баг-реквест автору). Баг заключается в том, что пакет ищет компоненты node_modules внутри себя и пытаются обратится за ними по пути, к примеру: "***C:\Project\node_modules\simple-icon-toggle\node_modules@angular\core\esm5***".

Так как данный пакет покрывал практически весь необходимый мне функцоинал - я использовал [**исходный код**](https://github.com/webilend/simple-icon-toggle/tree/master/src/app/modules/simple-icon-toggle) данного пакета для создания собственного компонента. К слову - компонент прекрасно работает с данным исходным кодом и без правок.

Еще раз спасибо [**overthesanity**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/303477/overthesanity) за подсказку.

*P/s: если вы знаете другие варианты решения - не стесняемся, оставляем комментарии. Буду премного благодарен.*